SELECT INTO a null literal of a specific type
How do I SELECT INTO a NULL value of a particular type?
For example, backing up data selectively and incorporating a DateFixed column that will start NULL and later be populated via SysUtcDateTime():
SELECT
    Thing.Id,
    Thing.SomeValue AS [BadValue],
    NULL AS [DateFixed]
INTO ThingValueFixBackup
FROM Thing
WHERE SomeValue IS WRONG SOMEHOW;


Just an aside but you shouldn't use "" quotes unless you really need them, [] is the standard quotes in sql server

@siggemannen ta, I appreciate the tip!

GETUTCDATE returns a datetime
So you can use
CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) AS DateFixed

to get a column of that type created with your SELECT ... INTO.
But you should consider using datetime2/SYSUTCDATETIME instead.
